# How to crawl for specific links inside a website?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have sucessfully crawled the **Headline** and the **Links**.

[image]
I would like to replace the **Summary** tab with **The Main Article** from the link (Since the Title and Summary are same anyways. )

`link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']`

(eg. https://www.vanglaini.org/tualchhung/103834)

Please help me modify my code.

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

list_with_headlines = []
list_with_summaries = []
list_with_links = []

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.a is None:
        continue
    headline = article.a.text.strip()
    summary = article.p.text.strip()
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']
    list_with_headlines.append(headline)
    list_with_summaries.append(summary)
    list_with_links.append(link)

news_csv = pd.DataFrame({
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
})

print(news_csv)
news_csv.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do request again inside for loop and get the tag text.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.vanglaini.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

list_with_headlines = []
list_with_summaries = []
list_with_links = []

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    if article.a is None:
        continue
    headline = article.a.text.strip()
    link = "https://www.vanglaini.org" + article.a['href']
    list_with_headlines.append(headline)
    list_with_links.append(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'lxml')
    list_with_summaries.append(soup.select_one(".pagesContent").text)

news_csv = pd.DataFrame({
    'Headline': list_with_headlines,
    'Summary': list_with_summaries,
    'Link' : list_with_links,
})

print(news_csv)
news_csv.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Csv will be like this.

[image]

Comment: @anddrewww This is what you are after?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. I will ask if I have any more questions and I hope you will answer. (I am new to python)

Comment: How to add new news to the csv in one single file? I mean continue crawling everyday and add new info in the same csv files

Comment: I have thiss error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279064/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-500