# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 500: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error after Installing my new MacOS. What could be the problem? CSV file is created but no information are written in.

My code is here
[How to crawl for specific links inside a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937799/how-to-crawl-for-specific-links-inside-a-website)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrew/PycharmProjects/Spidey/Spidey.py", line 29, in <module>
    news_csv.to_csv('z.csv')
  File "/Users/andrew/PycharmProjects/Spidey/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/Users/andrew/PycharmProjects/Spidey/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 172, in save
    self._save()
  File "/Users/andrew/PycharmProjects/Spidey/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 288, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/Users/andrew/PycharmProjects/Spidey/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 315, in _save_chunk
    self.cols, self.writer)
  File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 500: ordinal not in range(128)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: No. Answer 1 is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937799/how-to-crawl-for-specific-links-inside-a-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

`df= pd.read_csv('file_name.csv',encoding ='latin1')`
or changing the encoding to utf8